# Publish spans to Zipkin via Kafka using Sleuth

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have the following problem: i need to send traces to Zipkin via Kafka using Sleuth. Based on what i read in the documentation(https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_via_rabbitmq_or_kafka) all i need to do is to add `spring-kafka` dependency:

```
<dependency> 
       <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But i can't really see there to which kafka bootstrap server should i send or to which topic(is there some default topic that i should know about?).

Comment: Your example here is using RabbitMQ, not Kafka... You can refer to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_apache_kafka_binder to configure Kafka

Comment: using Kafka would mean:                                                                    <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: No... `spring-rabbit` won't be able to send data to Kafka, only RabbitMq

Comment: my bad: <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>, but i think that the idea is clear :)

Comment: Yup :) so now, have you use Spring Kafka before? Have you read that link I sent about how to configure it? There's no defaults that you're asking about